# Whats the best way to implement python TCP client?

Tags: python, multithreading, tcpclient

I need to write python script which performs several tasks:

1. read commands from console and send to server over `tcp/ip`
2. receive server response, process and make output to console.

What is the best way to create such a script? Do I have to create separate thread to listen to server response, while interacting with user in main thread? Are there any good examples?

Comment: Why would you need two threads? Do you care about messages from the server when the previous command has completed? Does the server care about what the user is typing while it's in the middle of a command? I don't feel like the two jobs ever need to happen in parallel

Comment: Than how do I receive messages from server and user commmands from console simultaneously?

Comment: Do you need to? Does the server ever send something that is not in response to a command? Can't it just alternate between command and response? ie `while True: get_cmd(); send_to_server(); dispay_response()`

Comment: Yes sometimes server sends something which is not a response yo a previous user input

Comment: You'll need to be careful with the console then - what should happen if the server has output to print when the user is halfway through typing a command?

Answer (score 1):

Calling for a *best way* or *code examples* is rather off topic, but this is too long to be a comment.

There are three general ways to build those *terminal emulator like* applications :

- multiple processes - the way the good old Unix `cu` worked with a `fork`
- multiple threads - a variant from the above using light way threads instad of processes
- using `select` system call with multiplexed io.

Generally, the 2 first methods are considered more straightforward to code with one thread (or process) processing upward communication while the other processes the downward one. And the third while being trickier to code is generally considered as more efficient

As Python supports multithreading, multiprocessing and `select` call, you can choose any method, with a slight preference for multithreading over multiprocessing because threads are lighter than processes and I cannot see a reason to use processes.

Following in just my *opinion*

Unless if you are writing a model for rewriting it later in a lower level language, I assume that performance is not the key issue, and my advice would be to use threads here.